# Problema con el código xml para el tablayout

Tags: android-studio

Muy buenas esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, he aquí nuevamente molestando, ya termine mi primer proyecto en android, y ahora realizando las pruebas y fallos, me di cuenta que este código que utilizo para el tablayout me da errores de render problem, pero al ejecutarlo corre excelente, no lo entiendo, este es el código para el xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".archivos.Frmpresupuesto">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#BA85D3C8">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/ingreso"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ingreso"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_color"
        android:icon="@drawable/ingresar"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/mano"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mano"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_color"
        android:icon="@drawable/mano"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/repuestos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Repuestos"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_color"
        android:icon="@drawable/repuestos"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/resumen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Resumen"
        android:textColor="@color/tab_color"
        android:icon="@drawable/resumen"/>
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

y este es el listado de errores de arroja un render probem
N°1:

```
Style ResourceReference{namespace=apk/res-auto, type=attr, name=textAppearanceButton} is not of type STYLE (instead attr)   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

N° 2:

```
Failed to find style with 2131032891   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

N° 3:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.res.Resources_Theme_Delegate.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources_Theme_Delegate.java:74)
at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:1610)
 at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:817)
 at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:3910)
 at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTextAppearance(AppCompatTextView.java:216)
 at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.setTextAppearance(MaterialTextView.java:110)
at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:3899)
at androidx.core.widget.TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(TextViewCompat.java:289)
at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.updateTab(TabLayout.java:2829)
at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.update(TabLayout.java:2858)
at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.setTab(TabLayout.java:2770)
at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.createTabView(TabLayout.java:1730)
at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.newTab(TabLayout.java:1013)
at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addTabFromItemView(TabLayout.java:881)
at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addViewInternal(TabLayout.java:1787)
at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addView(TabLayout.java:1777)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1131)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
```

ojala que me puedan ayudar con este problema, que me surgió ahora al momento de realizar las pruebas y fallos me di cuenta de este problema, si necesitan algo no duden  en solicitarlo y desde ya muchas gracias.